# Secure connection using transport client

Tags: elasticsearch

Need to connect to a secure elastic search which has https authentication using Transport client in java code. I have userId and password to connect however need example on how can we do it? I am using elasticsearch 5.6.0.

I was looking for xpack and sheild options but could not make use of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PreBuiltXpackTransportClient and could connect to the secured elastic search server. Refer documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/java-clients.html).