# Connect to Secured Elastic Search using java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I want to connect with my secured `ElasticSearch` and load my index data and store it in the variable. I found `RestHighLevelClient` in `java` which helped me in connecting with elastic search.

Here's the Code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;

public class ESConnect {
public static void main(String[] args){
    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));
    System.out.println(client); 
}
}
```

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But my `ElasticSearch` is protected with `username` and `password`. `Httphost` doesn't have `username` and `password` parameters. I found this [Secure connection using transport client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327118/secure-connection-using-transport-client). But there is no proper answer to connect with secured `ElasticSearch`. So i don't know how to connect my secured elastic search using java. Next, I have a `index` named `football_data` in `ElasticSearch`. I want to load the index data and store it in a variable using `java`. Help me to connect to secured `elasticSearch` and load index data using `java`. Please provide some solutions for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created this by elastic search [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_basic_authentication.html). You should refer them . For now do the following...

```
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));

RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200))
        .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        });

RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
```

Now as for getting data, you have to create a searchRequest with a query of your desire (I think Match query will do with scroll api if the data is more than 10000). Follow this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html).

Comment: Please approve my answer as the answer to your question if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. But I want get the data from Index of `ElasticSearch` and load it to the variable as a object. in java.  How to make it.

Comment: Do you have a schema of data stored in the index?

Comment: Yes....I have it. In python,`query = {'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match_all': {}}], 'must_not': [], 'should': []}}, 'size': 10000};
results = client.search(index='index name', body=query)`, i have done this to get data. But in java, i don't know

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link where you can see how to use search API.

Comment: Thank u so much. Can u show me sample usage with one of index. Since i am new to java coming from python, I can't make it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207655/discussion-between-paul-steven-and-vinit-pillai).